# Microsoft Excel 2010 Web Query Macro: Pulling Multiple Pages From One

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking to find some help on this Macro.. The idea is, upon execution the Macro will pull The Data from a Web Page (I.E http://www.link.com/id=7759) and place it into let's say Sheet2, and then Open up Page 2, and place it right below Page 1's Data in Sheet 2.... And So on and So on until a set Page Number.. Ideally I would like it just to pull The following in order;

Title
Artist
Type
Paper Size
Image Size
Retail Prize
Quantity

And further more it is ideal that is placed in proper columns and rows of 4 and 8 Rows down(Columns Across just like in the web page).

Any help on this would be greatly, greatly appreciated. I have done some research and found similar macros, sadly have had no luck getting them to work for me. Mainly VB's fail to go through as well.

Bit of useful info (maybe) I figured this out when I was trying to write my own, maybe it will save who ever helps some time..

```
.WebTables = "8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38"
```

Those are the tables for each item I want to put into the Que...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a sample method to get you going

Based on a few assumptions

- Workbook contains a Sheet to hold query data called "Query"
- Workbook contains a Sheet to put the data in called "AllData"
- All old data is removed on running the macro
- I think you need to include Table 7 in the qyuery
- Pages to process is hard coded as  `For Pg = 1 To 1` , change this to suit

.

```
Sub QueryWebSite()
    Dim shQuery As Worksheet, shAllData As Worksheet
    Dim clData As Range

    Dim qts As QueryTables
    Dim qt As QueryTable
    Dim Pg As Long, i As Long, n As Long, m As Long
    Dim vSrc As Variant, vDest() As Variant

    ' setup query
    Set shQuery = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Query")
    Set shAllData = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("AllData")

    'Set qt = shQuery.QueryTables(1)
    On Error Resume Next

    Set qt = shQuery.QueryTables("Liebermans")
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Err.Clear
        Set qt = shQuery.QueryTables.Add( _
            Connection:="URL;http://www.liebermans.net/productlist.aspx?id=7759&page=1", _
            Destination:=shQuery.Cells(1, 1))
        With qt
            .Name = "Liebermans"
            .WebSelectionType = xlSpecifiedTables
            .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
            .WebTables = "7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38"
            .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
            .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
            .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
            .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
            .WebDisableRedirections = False
            .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
        End With
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0

    i = InStr(qt.Connection, "&page=")

    ' clear old data
    shAllData.UsedRange.ClearContents
    shAllData.Cells(1, 1) = "Title"
    shAllData.Cells(1, 2) = "Artist"
    shAllData.Cells(1, 3) = "Type"
    shAllData.Cells(1, 4) = "Paper Size"
    shAllData.Cells(1, 5) = "Image Size"
    shAllData.Cells(1, 6) = "Price"
    shAllData.Cells(1, 7) = "Quantity"


    m = 0
    ReDim vDest(1 To 10000, 1 To 7)
    For Pg = 1 To 1
        ' Query Wb site
        qt.Connection = Left(qt.Connection, i + 5) & Pg
        qt.Refresh False

        ' Process data
        vSrc = qt.ResultRange
        n = 2
        Do While n < UBound(vSrc, 1)
            If vSrc(n, 1) <> "" And vSrc(n - 1, 1) = "" Then
                m = m + 1
                vDest(m, 1) = vSrc(n, 1)
            End If
            If vSrc(n, 1) Like "Artist:*" Then vDest(m, 2) = Trim(Mid(vSrc(n, 1), 8))
            If vSrc(n, 1) Like "Type:*" Then vDest(m, 3) = Trim(Mid(vSrc(n, 1), 6))
            If vSrc(n, 1) Like "Paper Size:*" Then vDest(m, 4) = Trim(Mid(vSrc(n, 1), 12))
            If vSrc(n, 1) Like "Image Size:*" Then vDest(m, 5) = Trim(Mid(vSrc(n, 1), 12))
            If vSrc(n, 1) Like "Retail Price:*" Then vDest(m, 6) = Trim(Mid(vSrc(n, 1), 14))
            If vSrc(n, 1) Like "Quantity in stock:*" Then vDest(m, 7) = Trim(Mid(vSrc(n, 1), 19))

            n = n + 1
        Loop
    Next

    ' Put data in sheet
    shAllData.Cells(2, 1).Resize(m, 7) = vDest

End Sub
```

Comment: @ChrisNeilsen This is PERFECT. Everything is actually just perfect, there is only one thing I would like to request for you to change if you would be so kind... in the AllData output... Instead of having the headers for; Artist, Type, Paper Size, Image Size. Could you Replace it with a header like Description, and merge the text together into one cell? That's what I was going to do before you went and did this AllData output file, Very great work though ^_^.

Comment: @Leaum, I'm sure you can cope with making that change yourself.  BTW if you find the answer helpfull, you should accept it.

Comment: @ChrisNeilsen I accepted it xD Sorry I just forgot to last night, it was late. After a TON of trial and errors I still have not made that change... The only way I would know to do would be to use something like & ". " & (m, 4) after (m, 3) but that does not work -sighs-

Comment: @Leaum about to AllData output: are you it all in one columns, so each item is in only one cell?

Comment: @ChrisNeilsen I have figured out how to get the desired outcome I would like for that.. I guess I just needed some sleep and to look closer at your Code... I did forget to request also to include Liebermans ID#, I have been trying to figured out how to get it to stream that data in as well with the rest... For a while now, with no real luck.. It streams in blanks. I added  shAllData.Cells(1, 8) = "Lieberman's ID"   and If vSrc(n, 1) Like "Lieberman's ID#:*" Then vDest(m, 8) = Trim(Mid(vSrc(n, 1), 22))  < The 23 on the end is a guess, since I am not sure how you came to the other numbers.

Comment: @Leaum To add ID use If vSrc(n, 1) Like "Lieberman's ID[#]:*" Then vDest(m, 6) = Trim(Mid(vSrc(n, 1), 18))  The [#] is because the like operator uses # as a wild card to match any digit, enclosing in [] makes it match the # character.  The number 18 is the length of the string up to the :

Comment: That does not appear to be working.. (Just so you know, I would like it to go to Column H I believe that would be M, 8) And when I try to change it to m, 8 it says subscript is out of range

Comment: @ChrisNeilsen Ahhhh! Nevermind, I got it. I had to change the ReDim as well from 1 To 7 to 8! Thank you Chris!