# Webpage query and import data to excel

Tags: excel, web

I am trying to extract specific data from several web pages under https://support.software.dell.com/appassure/kb

I am interested in pulling the title of the article, the last Updated on field, the KB views and the ratings (four fields in total)

The default number of pages for all KB articles is 40 and a basic web query in Excel that I tried didn't work.

I also reviewed [Microsoft Excel 2010 Web Query Macro: Pulling Multiple Pages From One](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5839454/microsoft-excel-2010-web-query-macro-pulling-multiple-pages-from-one) but it did not work.

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To loop the sites you need to do it with a for loop like

```
For i = 1 to 40
  ....
    ... = "https://support.software.dell.com/appassure/kb?p=" & i
  ....
next
```

(for me the import worked fine)

I simply ran a quick check:

```
Sub test()
  Dim i As Long
  For i = 1 To 40
    MsgBox "get page number" & i
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="URL;https://support.software.dell.com/appassure/kb?p=" & i, Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
        .Name = "testing"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .WebSelectionType = xlEntirePage
        .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
        .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
        .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
        .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
        .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
        .WebDisableRedirections = False
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
  Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply - please could you post the full example you ran?  I'm not sure how / where to embed your example and output out the 4 required fields.

Comment: That's fantastic Dirk - Thank You!  I was curious do you know a method so all the 4 fields title, last updated, views and rating could be output as a column for each field (to enable easy sorting - such as sorting by the last updated or the most views)?

Comment: Now you need to run through the imported cells and check for the values... a bunch of work to create the code for this... I'll look into it if I'm home again...

Comment: Thanks Dirk - I used the formula below in an adjacent column and it transposes the row to columns nicely.

I really appreciate your help with the example you posted.
<br>
`=OFFSET($A$1,(ROW()-1)*5+INT((COLUMN()-3)),MOD(COLUMN()-3,1))`